# Interpreting Toad's Query Times for more than 500 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

When I execute a query in Toad that returns more than 500 rows, does the number of milliseconds on the bottom left represent how long it took to execute the entire query, or to fetch 500 rows?

[image]

For example, the above query returns 7000 rows. Did the entire query take 1000ms, or just the act of fetching 500 rows?

Comment: This is the time from opening a cursor to 500-th row fetching from it.  Maybe `FIRST_ROWS` hint is turned on in TOAD options.

Comment: If you really want to fetch all the rows, press Ctrl+End. However, if you're testing the performance of the query, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that by default Toad only fetches the first 500 records and stops.

This can be confirmed by tracing the TOAD session and creating a `tkprof` report of the resulting trace file.

In my test case, I created a table with one million rows:

```
 create table a_million_rows as
 select rownum as x
   from dual
connect by level <= 1000000;
```

Then, I ran the `select * from a_million_rows` statement in Toad.

According to the `tkprof` report, only 501 rows were retrieved from the database:

```
select *
from
 a_million_rows


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        1      0.00       0.00          5          4          0         501
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      0.00       0.00          5          4          0         501

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 93

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
    501  TABLE ACCESS FULL A_MILLION_ROWS (cr=4 pr=5 pw=0 time=0 us cost=35 size=13951951 card=1073227)
```